Newtonsoft.Json v11 at GitHub is the same of v13 at NuGet?
I forked Newtonsoft.Json to include isoDataOnly conversion at the code; however I have some packages, like quartz, that use the version 13, and I realize that the Assembly version at master is 11.
At workaround I change at my local project the assembly version tag to 13, but I don't know if everything will work.
Can anyone tell if is right this or I made something wrong.

We can't tell you if everything will work or not. If you have tests, run them. If they run fine, you should be good. Ultimately though, it's your call, and the consumers of your library's calls, whether that's good enough.

Yeah, for some reason the 13.0.3 tag also has assembly version 11.0.0.0
